# Изменить состояние в классе для 2 way binding на js

Tags: javascript, классы, binding

Есть класс для создания двухсторонней связи на джиесе, подобной по смыслу тем, что применяются во вью, реакте, ангуляре и т.д. Я отобрал его на просторах интернета среди сотен подобных, но не до конца понимаю, как его использовать.

Простыми словами, задача приведенного ниже класса связывать инпут с другим элементом на странице, чтобы при заполнении инпута текст из него выводился в элементе и наоборот, если меняется значение StateObserver.state то обновлялся инпут.

Скрипт работает, когда я меняю текст в инпуте все обновляется, но как мне обновить состояние, например, по таймауту в качестве значения заносить в него рандомную цифру? Чтобы обновился инпут.

Таким образом должно получиться так, что если мы по таймеру будем обновлять состояние, то должен обновляться инпут.

```
// create a base class to handle state
class StateObserver extends HTMLElement {
 constructor () {
   super()
    StateObserver.instances.push(this)
  }
 stateUpdate (update) {
   StateObserver.lastState = StateObserver.state
    StateObserver.state = update
    StateObserver.instances.forEach((i) => {
     if (!i.onStateUpdate) return
     i.onStateUpdate(update, StateObserver.lastState)
    })
  }
}

StateObserver.instances = []
StateObserver.state = {}
StateObserver.lastState = {}

// create a web component which will react to state changes
class CustomReactive extends StateObserver {
 onStateUpdate (state, lastState) {
   if (state.someProp === lastState.someProp) return
    this.innerHTML = `input is: ${state.someProp}`
  }
}
customElements.define('custom-reactive', CustomReactive)

class CustomObserved extends StateObserver {
 connectedCallback () {
   this.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
     this.stateUpdate({ someProp: e.target.value })
    })
  }
}
customElements.define('custom-observed', CustomObserved)
```

Использование

```
<custom-observed>
  <input>
</custom-observed>
<br />
<custom-reactive></custom-reactive>
```

Comment: А никак - это же односторонняя (не двусторонняя) связь, то есть лишь прослушивание события: усложнили листенер объектным подходом, и все. Настоящая реактивность в современном JS базируется на интерфейсе `Proxy`, и некотором бойлерплейте для DOM (требуется расширение прототипа элемента т.к. DOM-объекты проксировать нельзя, это внешний апи). Ну а в старом (ES5) - было на геттерах и сеттерах вместо проксирования объекта.

Comment: Я нашел его на каком-то "копипаст стартапе" qastack.ru/programming/16483560/how-to-implement-dom-data-binding-in-javascript там рассматриваются различные методы, этот мне приглянулся, в контексте страницы я подумал, что это то, что мне нужно

Comment: Хех, ты нашел паразитирующий на enSO сайтик. Вот правильная ссылка: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483560/how-to-implement-dom-data-binding-in-javascript - и там в основном одностороннее связывание обсуждается (изначально). Короче, не совсем то что хочешь найти, если я верно понял.

Comment: Задача решается в общем и целом так: пишется некоторое подобие Observable (на `Proxy`, реализует внутренние обновления и вызов внешних коллбэков, по изменению значений свойств наблюдаемого экземпляра JS-объекта), как база ➝ пишется объектный тип "поддержки DOM", наследующий первый объект (добавляет в реализацию метод монтирования на экземпляр DOM-объекта, листенерами и `MutationObserver`'ом связывает обновление "своего" элемента со своим стейтом, предоставляет хелпер-методы) ➝ пишется объект обертки (предоставляет упрощенный апи для клиентского кода, инкапсулируя объект Наблюдаемого).

Comment: Можно конечно обойтись одним объектным типом который будет изначально поддерживать связывание с DOM, но я бы все-таки разделил "ядро" реализации реактивности и специфичные для DOM вещи - потому что если захочется например стейт-менеджер написать, эти специфичные вещи будут впустую раздувать объект и тормозить выполнение проверками на наличие биндинга состояния данных к состоянию элемента. К тому же, вероятно потребуется еще раз унаследовать базовый объект для создания "адаптера" к источникам данных (бэкэнд/сторейж/...), если захочется еще и к ним реактивность подвести.

Comment: У меня CRM система на нативном джиесе где много динамичных счетчиков в интерфейсе (кол-во задач, продаж и т.д.) 1 раз в минуту аякс дергает апи и чекает на наличие чего-то новенького, если есть, то на фронт летит джейсон с циферками и команда распихать их по селекторам, и тут я делаю innerHTML, следующий проект буду 100п писать на вью или реакте, а на этом хотел немного реактивности добавить чтоб заодно глубже в эту тему погрузиться и лучше понять суть.

Comment: Геттеры, сеттеры, прокси, низкоуровневое апи, объекты и т.д. я уже как бы "наблатыкался" и вершков нахватался, многое понятно, но поскольку у меня кор компетишен бекенд, однозначно на чем-то остановиться пока не могу, буду еще ресерчить, смущает то, что 10 разных экспертов советуют 10 разных вещей, и все убедительны. Решил пока остановиться на этом скрипте https://github.com/eddyystop/CrazyGlue В любом случае, спасибо за ответы.